# Filtering microposts feed by User profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications, rails-activerecord

On our site we have a user profile page where we want to display all microposts that are relevant to that User's profile.

In our microposts table we have a belongs_to_id column and a user_id (defines who the micropost is to from)

We are trying to match the belongs_to_id with the user_id. This is so that when a profile is viewed, only microposts where the belongs_to_id matches the user_id of the profile being viewed are displayed. How could we go about doing this?

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :belongs_to_id

  belongs_to :user


  validates :content, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 240 }
  validates :user_id, :presence => true

  default_scope :order => 'microposts.created_at DESC'

    # Return microposts from the users being followed by the given user.
    scope :from_users_followed_by, lambda { |user| followed_by(user) }

    private

      # Return an SQL condition for users followed by the given user.
      # We include the user's own id as well.
      def self.followed_by(user)
        following_ids = %(SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                      WHERE follower_id = :user_id)
        where("user_id IN (#{following_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id",
          { :user_id => user })
    end
  end
```

UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,   :only => :destroy

      def index
         @title = "All users"
         @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
      end

      def show

          @user = User.find(params[:id])
          @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(:page => params[:page])
          @title = @user.name
          @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with a named scope in the MicroPost class only if you want the posts where the user_id AND belongs_to are the same:

micropost.rb

```
class MicroPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :relevant_to_user, lambda{|i|
   where("user_id = ? AND belongs_to_id = ?", i, i)}
end
```

then in the controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @microposts = MicroPost.relevant_to_user(@user.id)
end
```

EDIT: If you only need to find microposts where the belongs_to_id matches a value (in this case current_user.id) use:

```
def show
  @microposts = MicroPost.where(:belongs_to_id=>current_user.id)
end
```

Comment: @scudbomb - No problem, glad to help.  Important: To ensure any of your future questions get attention, it will help both of us if you up-vote this answer AND set it as accepted.  Thanks!

Comment: I am extremely new to stack overflow, rails, and coding in general. It appears that i can't upvote until i get to 15 reputation. How do i get there faster?

Comment: @scudbomb ah, yeah I forgot about that upvote requirement.  No worries on that. Your rep will increase as you ask good questions (and answer them too.)  It'll get up there.  Good luck! -md

Comment: just realized the code isnt working, its only showing microposts where the `user_id` and `belongs_to_id` of the post matches. We want only to display posts where the `belongs_to_id` of the post matches the `user_id` of the current user. Complicated I know, but we're really trying to optimize these feeds and having a hard time doing so.

Comment: Okay. Sorry, I completely misunderstood your question.  If that's the case it's much simpler and would be the same as Alex D's answer below: Micropost.where(:belongs_to_id=>current_user.id).  I'll update the above.

Comment: perfect we're running it right now. whats your email? feel free to DM me via twitter (at)its_scutti or to my email address chris.scutti@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why Microposts have *both* `belongs_to_id` and `user_id`. But if you want to find all the Microposts whose `belongs_to_id` matches a given User's ID, all you need is:

```
@microposts = Micropost.find_all_by_belongs_to_id(@user.id)
```

Comment: Hope this was helpful! If it solved your problem, please accept (an upvote would also be appreciated).

Comment: I'm extremely new to stack overflow and coding, and it appears that i can't upvote until i reach 15 reputation

Comment: I just upvoted your question, that should give you the needed rep.